# How do Upload and execute a file in a server PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I try the code below:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'teste');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($db, "LOAD DATA INFILE 'dados.txt' INTO TABLE teste FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (nome, idade, sexo)" );

echo "OK";
```

it returns ok but none row is insert in the table.

my file test is:

```
"Name Example 1",15,"F"
"Name Example 2",23,"M"
"Name Example 3",15,"M"
```

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Yes. it's possible.

Comment: I dont try cause I dont have an idea to do it. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'datafile.txt' INTO TABLE [Table_Name];
```

Create data file as below:

1 Test1 Name1

2 Test2 Name2

3 Test2 Name2

Then create table according to correct data types and names.

CREATE TABLE [Table_Name](id INT, col1 VARCHAR(255), col2 VARCHAR(255));

```
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
if (!$sql) {
   die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database_name");
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'datafile.txt'" .
                  " INTO TABLE [Table_Name] FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'");
if (!$result) {
   die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}
```

datafile.txt path should give correctly.

Refer:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-local-infile-handler.php

Comment: can you explain me a example of file?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: pls check this way

Comment: Pls do not do this kind of thing. Keep previous question here. This question add as new questions. Unless given answers not tally with question.